# Floating shelf: Rounded vs. Rectangular brackets?

Tags: kitchens, drill, shelving

What are the pros and cons of each option?

I guess the rounded one means the diameter of the hole in the wall should be very big, while no difficult affixing is required on the shelf, you just drill a rounded hole on the shelf and that's it.

With rectangular, it's the opposite. You can drill two small holes in the walls to install the bracket, but the shelf need to fit both the rounded pin and the rectangular shape of the bracket.

Am I right? What are your thoughts? I'm looking for something easy and budget friendly. already have the shelves which require drilling.

[image]

[image]

VS

Comment: +10 and some more points for you for providing photos

Comment: The top bracket uses a pair of appropriate fasteners to attach it to the wall while spreading the load across a significant area on the face of the wall. The bottom appears to be designed specifically for insertion into a masonry wall, though it might suffice buried in a stud or other suitable blocking.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely clear if you are making your own shelves or not, but it sounds like you are not buying the shelves and brackets as a combo.

In both cases, do not underestimate the task of drilling the holes in the shelves to accept the rods.  The holes must be perpendicular to the surface (in this case the edge of the shelves). Typically we use a drill press to make perpendicular holes, but it won't work for a hole this big and this deep.  I hope you have figured out this part.  If the holes are not perpendicular your shelves will be leaning up or down.

The mortise to accept the rectangular part of the rod can be easily done with a chisel or a router.

That being said, I think the first option is a bit easier to install.  All you need to do is have them correctly spaced out and level.  The rectangular plates ensure your rod will be perpendicular to the wall.  However, for the 2nd option, you need to drill the holes and ensure they are perpendicular to the wall.  Not a problem since it's drywall and you can make adjustments, but make sure you don't hit place your rod where the studs are.  Just more planning and tweaking.

If you can make perfect holes in the shelves, attaching the rods to the walls should be piece of cake with whichever option you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The second option you show uses the pin as a lever to expand the mounting anchor. So you use the hex bar as a screw that hooks up in the wall. Rectangular option requires separate screws/anchors.

I guess the drawback of the second option (one round hole per peg) is that you can't fully control how deep the peg needs to go into the shelf. You might find yourself with a peg too long for those holes because anchor couldn't fully open up for some reason.

[Image from Walmart website](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Unique-Bargains-PP-plastic-Hardened-Steel-Floating-Shelf-Bracket-DIY-Invisible-Wall-Mounts-8-54-Length-4-Pcs/669963381):
[image: walmart mounting item]